# how to open terminal in spyder (already installed)

Tags: terminal, spyder

I installed spyder terminal with conda , and I accidentally closed it and i can't find a way to open it again I tried installing it but it shows me that it is already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) All available panes are present in the menu `View > Panes`.

Comment: is there a way to create new file with spyder in the terminal? That is, similarly to Vim, or Nano... "spyder test1.py" ?

Comment: @RoiMinuit, you mean create a file in Spyder directly from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, Sir. Just like when you do "vim text.py" and it starts a new file for you to edit